# Multiples CMake in a project

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm developing a C++ application that use a library that i develop before. I don`t want link the binary to my new project because who use another plataform need rebuild then. So, i whant attach the cmake file from this another project to this new one and when i build then, build the library too. Someone know how i do this? Thanks Alot.
String Library: https://github.com/TigreFramework/String
My new CMake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4)
project(DataBase)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp DataBase.cpp DataBase.h String.h libString.a)
add_executable(DataBase ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

EDIT 01:

Now i can compile with this CMake:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4)
project(String)

include_directories(./include/cryptopp563/)
#link_directories(./include/cryptopp563/)
add_subdirectory(./include/cryptopp563/)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

find_library(cryptopp include/cryptopp563/)


set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp String.cpp String.h RsaString.cpp RsaString.h)

add_library(RsaString STATIC RsaString.cpp)
add_library(String STATIC String.cpp)

#add_executable(Teste ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

But, if i use de add_executable i receive this error:

```
[  1%] Built target String
[  2%] Built target RsaString
[  2%] Linking CXX executable Teste
[ 97%] Built target cryptopp
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"CryptoPP::RandomPool::IncorporateEntropy(unsigned char const*, unsigned long)", referenced from:
vtable for CryptoPP::AutoSeededRandomPool in String.cpp.o
"CryptoPP::RandomPool::GenerateIntoBufferedTransformation(CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned long long)", referenced from:
vtable for CryptoPP::AutoSeededRandomPool in String.cpp.o
"CryptoPP::RandomPool::RandomPool()", referenced from:
CryptoPP::AutoSeededRandomPool::AutoSeededRandomPool(bool, unsigned int) in String.cpp.o
.............. MORE LINES HIDEM HERE .................
"non-virtual thunk to CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation::GetWaitObjects(CryptoPP::WaitObjectContainer&, CryptoPP::CallStack const&)", referenced from:
vtable for CryptoPP::SourceTemplate<CryptoPP::FileStore> in RsaString.cpp.o
vtable for CryptoPP::FileSource in RsaString.cpp.o
vtable for CryptoPP::AutoSignaling<CryptoPP::InputRejecting<CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation> > in RsaString.cpp.o
vtable for CryptoPP::InputRejecting<CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation> in RsaString.cpp.o
vtable for CryptoPP::InputRejecting<CryptoPP::Filter> in RsaString.cpp.o
vtable for CryptoPP::Sink in RsaString.cpp.o
vtable for CryptoPP::PK_DecryptorFilter in RsaString.cpp.o
...
"non-virtual thunk to CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation::GetMaxWaitObjectCount() const", referenced from:
vtable for CryptoPP::SourceTemplate<CryptoPP::FileStore> in RsaString.cpp.o
vtable for CryptoPP::FileSource in RsaString.cpp.o
vtable for CryptoPP::AutoSignaling<CryptoPP::InputRejecting<CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation> > in RsaString.cpp.o
vtable for CryptoPP::InputRejecting<CryptoPP::BufferedTransformation> in RsaString.cpp.o
vtable for CryptoPP::InputRejecting<CryptoPP::Filter> in RsaString.cpp.o
vtable for CryptoPP::Sink in RsaString.cpp.o
vtable for CryptoPP::PK_DecryptorFilter in RsaString.cpp.o
...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
CMakeFiles/Teste.dir/build.make:146: recipe for target 'Teste' failed
gmake[2]: *** [Teste] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:141: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/Teste.dir/all' failed
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Teste.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
gmake: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use add_subdirectory https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_subdirectory.html

or simple include
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/include.html

also there is feature of cmake called external project,
which allow you to build project with any build system

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/ExternalProject.html

Comment: This should be a comment. [Link-only answers are discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Comment: @PedroSoares I don't get it, if you use library in your `Teste`, you have to use `target_link_libraries(Teste library)`, why you think that it can use some functionality without linking?

Comment: When i put target_link_libraries i receive the error from my IDE Error:Cannot specify link libraries for target "cryptopp" which is not built by this project.

Comment: You link `Teste`, why report error `cryptopp`? Any way move `IDE` remove from discussion, use `cmake` from command line, until error will be resoled